# Recommended Database Structure for User's Information

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to figure out how I should go about building my database structure (tables) for user information on my website. The kinds of information that I will be storing (at this time anyways) are:

- About Me
- Birthday (January, 1, 1970)
- Sex (Male/Female)
- Interested In: (Male, Female, Both)
- Relationship Status: (Single, In a Relationship, Engaged, Married)
- Website: (mywebsite.com)
- From: (Cupertino, California)

So this is the type of information I will be storing for now. My question basically is, should I have this be one table only? Or would it be better to split the information up depending on what it was (my users have a unique ID which would go along with each table of information, obviously). So I'm not sure if I should have a table exclusively for Birthdays with the columns: userID, Month, Day, Year; or what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a user only needs to store one piece of information for an attribute, then you don't need a separate table for it.  For example, a user only has one birthday.  The only reason you would need a separate `Birthdays` table would be if you want to store multiple birthdays for the same userid.  Each one of the attributes you've listed look like they'd be fine in one `Users` table.

As for splitting up `Birthdays` into the columns: userID, Month, Day, Year, it all depends on how you're going to use that information.  Will you ever need to know *just* the Month, Day, or Year that a user's birthday falls on?  If that's a common need, you might want to store them separately.  It's usually not, so you probably just want to store it as a single Date value.

**Note:** You can take a look at the schema used by Stack Overflow by checking out the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).  They keep a similar collection of data in one Users table.

Comment: I would avoid splitting birth dates into parts, because it's a very specific denormalization and a pain in the ass if you just want "the date". Split *only* if there's a *proven* (hard evidence) performance problem that can be addressed this way, and importantly that *needs* addressing. It would be a classic mistake of "optimizing early" to start the design with split dates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Previously i have only used one table for all of this kind of information, and I have been intending to continue to do so up until now, however I am in the final stages of developing my website for its launch date, and I am trying to come up with the best way to allow flexibility to the data in the future. Such as for the birthdays columns part, as of right now I don't know exactly how I will be using that information, but I would like to have it stored in the best way possible so I can use it any way I want to in the future.

Comment: @Bohemian I stuck with that example because it's the one the OP used.  A better example might be an address.  Sometimes you want the city, state, zip, etc. in separate fields, but sometimes an address is just treated as one atomic piece of data.  It really depends on how it's going to be used.

Comment: @DylanCross You're welcome.  I think one table is the way to go with the information you've shown.  Each one of those pieces of data looks like it will have a single value per userId, so keeping it all in one table makes sense.  As Bohemian mentioned, it's strongly preferred to store a date as a single value unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: @BilltheLizard +1 Didn't know about the data explorer. Good advice too!

Comment: One thing I would also like to be able to do is have privacy settings, so each field could be set by the user as either Private, Public, or Hidden. for example, Birthday is hidden, website is public, relationship status is visible only by friends, etc. I'm not sure how I would design the database(s) for this to work well together.

Comment: @DylanCross You could just add those fields to the same Users table.  You need one flag for each attribute that users can control the visibility of.  It's still a one-to-one relationship with the userId, so there's no need for a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

In the vast majority of cases, I've seen what you're asking being stored in one table - usually `user` or `users`.

Perhaps including a number of other elements too:

> - user id (unique)
> - registration date
> - status (live/expired/banned)
> - user hash
> - plus a variety of others...

Honestly - It's dependent on what you're building and how it's built, but my advice would be to start simple.

On your point about birthdays, just store the date in mysql date format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

That way, you can manipulate it in a variety of ways using mysql functions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, and please see my comment to Bill the Lizard's answer, it can be applied directly to your answer as well.

Comment: @DylanCross Indeed. I've known a single users table used for millions of users, so it's not like it won't scale...

Comment: Well, it's more of the information being stored so I can use it in different ways than I may even intend to use it now, the way I have previously done it doesn't always allow me to do that (or very easily anyways)